# XCode 4.4 option to warn about deprecated functions reverts to "Yes".. why? Bug?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

In XCode 4.4.1 on OS X 10.8.1, when I select in my project settings "No" for the option to warn about deprecated functions, it works if I build right away... but if I go and edit some code then come back to it, then the build settings will have reverted to "Yes" for that option. Why does it keep reverting back, instead of saving my preference? Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the XCode caches in /Users/Library/Caches and /Library/Caches and restarting the computer after running Onyx and deleting other caches fixed this problem.